# Is it necessary to install FTP on Azure Ubuntu VM to write files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I just created an azure vm with Ubuntu and noticed that I am able to FTP into it without having installed an FTP app like vsFTP.  It just works, as far as FTP viewing goes.

I can read files from my Django project in the var/www directory, but I am unable to upload.  Can these permissions be managed without installing an FTP application?  Or is the FTP connection normally allowed by Linux just because the port is open, whereas an FTP program is needed for more advanced management?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting via FTP and not SFTP?

Comment: No actually, I'm just using SmartFtp GUI, enter the url with no prefix, and I don't see any indication one way or another.  But I did open the ftp port... I'll try closing the ftp port and see if I can still get in...

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you are using SFTP, which is provided by the ssh server that comes installed by default.

Comment: To fix permissions, just do it as you always would: examine the target files and directories, who you are connecting as, and then fix things up using chown and chmod.

Comment: You're right, I didn't even have an FTP port like I thought. (I know i don't need to mention this, but obviously I'm new with linux)